# How to throw a parseException in a switch statement?

Tags: java, unit-testing

To increase my projects code coverage, I need to reach the branch **ParseException** in this method:

```
public String filterMessage(String actionIn, String messageIn) {
        String message = null;
        try{
            switch (actionIn) {
            //EDIT: this calls the other class causing parseexception
            case "search":
                message = (srvmt.SearchEngine(messageIn));
                break;
            default:
                message = messageIn;
                break;
            }

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Encountered parse exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Instincts are that we must put a String that is "illegal", that can't be parsed because it isn't actually a String, but how do you place something like that without causing a compile error (like putting an int to cause faulse parsing). Any ideas how to test this catch "branch"?

EDIT: This is the method the case above calls which uses a parse exception

```
public  String SearchEngine(String removecommand)
{//INCOMING-SEARCH¿Email¿@gmail.com
    JSONArray databaseupdated = read(pathdatabase);
    ArrayList<String> matchlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject mainobj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray userinfo = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    for(int i = 0; i<databaseupdated.size(); i++)
    {
        String option = "";
        String value = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(removecommand);
            option = (String) json.get("option");
            value = (String) json.get("value");
            mainobj= (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(databaseupdated.get(i).toString());
            userinfo =(JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(mainobj.get(mainobj.keySet().toString().substring(1,mainobj.keySet().toString().length()-1)).toString());
            obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(userinfo.get(0).toString());  
        } //EDIT, there is a lot of code not explained, but here is the parse EXCEPTION
          catch (ParseException e) {
            return "false";
        }
        if(SearchEngineTRUEFALSE1(mainobj.keySet().toString().substring(1,mainobj.keySet().toString().length()-1),option,value))
        {
            matchlist.add(obj.get("Email").toString());
        }
    }
    return matchlist.toString();
}
```

Comment: which method you call in switch that can throw ParseException ? If none, you can erase the catch it'll raise the code coverage too.

Comment: I don't get your question. Some action within your try tells you it is throwing a parse exception. What prevents you pushing in a string value ... that absolutely must lead to such an exception?

Comment: The method won't run if the given parameters are not a string.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I can't delete it because in the cases i call a method which needs a catch block

Comment: @coders Post the code throwing the ParseException so we can see what can be done here

Comment: @coders If you no this method you know which kind of string will throw a ParseException. It it is a method of standard java or well known framework you can give us it.

Comment: @ArthurEirich  I have posted the method my switch case causes which needs to handle an exception

Comment: Side note: you want to study java coding styleguides. Your names get the casiness all wrong.

Comment: @Jägermeister yah i know, this project is old but needs testing

Comment: So you just need to pass a wrong JSON string in your test case. I think it'is not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`throw new ParseException("Parse exception description you want");`

Comment: How is he supposed to do that from **inside** his production code?! The point is that he needs to able to have it thrown when running a test; but you really really never ever want a statement like this in your production code, just to reach coverage.

Answer (score 0):

you could throw an exception as Michaël told and if you are using Junit to test, you could do something like this using the expected annotation to catch it

```
@Test(expected= ParseException)
public void testFilterMessage() {
    filterMessage(illformedString1, illformedString2);
}
```

Comment: Thats my question though, how do you form an illformedstring that is a string? A null won't work cause it throws null pointer exception

Comment: my bad, i fixed it, but  you could define input strings that could cause an error since you know the function behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Given your updated question:

You want to look into using a mocking framework.

Basically you have to enable your class under test so that you can provide a **mocked** srvmt object to it. And you configure that mock to simply throw that exception upon calls to the method it owns. Well, one of your test case configures the mock to throw that exception; other testcases would configure the mock to return other results.

In other words: search for terms like "dependency injection" and "mocking"; study and apply.

Comment: I would know how to use mocks to test this exception, but the project is "old" and not structured (nor am i allowed) for mocking.

Comment: Well, you don't have to use a mocking framework. You can always create mock classes yourself! And honestly: if your hands are really handcuffed like this; and you are not allowed to do the things that make sense; you better turn back to your manager **now** and tell him that he is asking you to waste your time doing bullshit actions that only cost money but do not result in **any** return-on-investment. You see: we are not wizards here. If you are trapped in a room, and all doors are "locked (and you aren't allowed to unlock them)"; well; we can only tell you that you are trapped.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Cheers. I will bring this on the table.

Comment: Not sure where I got that from, but there is a quote that might help you putting things on the table: "Following agile principles/practices can lead to high coverage numbers. And sometimes you are told to achieve high coverage numbers. There is a subtle difference between the two". Hope that makes sense ;-)